# How do I output Ping Success or Failure in one command, rather than two?

Tags: batch-file, ping

Here is a snippet of my current code (which works):

```
PING <ip-address> |find "TTL=">nul && ECHO Responsive> <filename>
PING <ip-address> |find "TTL=">nul || ECHO Unresponsive> <filename>
```

In doing a bit of [research](http://ss64.com/nt/ping.html) I've found that checking `ERRORLEVEL` can give incorrect results at times, so I chose to use the above method for logging the success or failure of `PING`. I also think it looks a bit cleaner.

**The problem** I have with it is that in the case where the ip address is not pingable, the command gets called twice and each ping command takes a while to complete. Also, in the (worst case) scenario where a computer is about to become un-pingable during the first command, it's possible that I'll get both results in my log file. So I'm wondering how to write these two lines as one ping command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
PING <ip-address> |find "TTL=">nul && ECHO Responsive> <filename> || ECHO Unresponsive> <filename>
```

Because || executes if the last command wasn't executed succesfully, **or wasn't executed at all**, so if the previous echo didn't fire this one will. For more information about this look [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)